# Pip.exe is already installed. How do I use it?

Tags: powershell, pip

I've seen on several websites to go to a "command prompt" and type in "python get-pip.exe". I don't have a file that is labeled as "get-pip.exe" so I am not sure where this is coming from. I have pip.exe, pip3.exe, and pip34.exe. I don't know how to do the "path" change that is discussed on several forums either. I am using Windows PowerShell as a "command prompt", but I do not know how to "run" pip.exe in it.

Update:
The below Stack Overflow is what I was going on for "get-pip.exe"
[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: What websites tell you to do that command, we need more context.

Comment: `get-pip.exe` is never mentioned in that question nor in any of the answers. `get-pip.py` is there, but that is a python script not a program. As to how to use `pip.exe` what [in the documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) do you not understand that made you come here and ask your question?

Answer (score 3):

If you have pip.exe already, then all you need is to modify your PATH so that pip.exe is in it and then you'll be able to run `pip` commands. You can do something like this:

```
$Env:PATH += ";" + "C:\Python34\Scripts\"
```

Or, if you want to make the change permanently, you can do it this way:

```
$Scope = "User"
$ScopePath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $Scope)
$ScopePath += ";" + "C:\Python34\Scripts\"
$Env:PATH += ";" + "C:\Python34\Scripts\" # also change the current process
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $ScopePath, $Scope)
```

From an *elevated* PowerShell window, you can use `$Scope = "Machine"`

Regardless of which of those you do, you should now be able to `pip list` or `pip install lxlml` etc.

Comment: Great solution!